# Visual basic Shell %USERPROFILE%

Tags: shell

I'm trying to make a folder with an visual basic program using Shell

```
           Shell("md %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\projectfiles2")
```

It doesn't understand %USERPROFILE% though and that's a problem.

How can I make the program understand that %USERPROFILE% means "C:\Users\User\"?

Sorry I'm a noob at visual basic still.

Answer (score 1):

Try to execute from shell: `mkdir %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\projectfiles2` or Write a new script in visual basic

```
Dim user() as string
Form1_load...
user=My.Computer.User.Name.split("\")
shell("cmd.exe /c mkdir " & user(1) & " \AppData\Roaming\projectfiles2")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this: `C:Users\%Username%\etc\`
That will show the username in the string